# error 'there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first'

Tags: c#, ado.net

runtime error 'there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first'

```
objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT field1, field2 FROM sourcetable", objConn);

objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (objDataReader.Read())
{
objInsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (3, '" + objDataReader[0] + "')", objConn);
objInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//Here is the error
}
objDataReader.Close();
```

I cannot define any stored procedure here.
Any help would we appreciated.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475195/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c/20535263#20535263

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about pulling the data into a DataSet via Fill and then iterate through that to perform your insert via NonQuery?

```
IDbDataAdapter da;
IDbCommand selectCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM sourcetable";
connection.Open();
DataSet selectResults= new DataSet();
da.Fill(selectResults); // get dataset
selectCommand.Dispose();
IDbCommand insertCommand;

foreach(DataRow row in selectResults.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (3, '" + row["columnName"].ToString() + "'";   
}
insertCommand.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: could you please provide me the syntax or example?

Answer (score 82):

No need to do all that, just turn on MARS and your problem will get solved. In your connection string just add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

Comment: Verified this with SQL 2008. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/78d3989a-8975-4930-998d-1eb907966f57

Comment: Works for me. SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Works for me. SQL Server 2008.

Comment: MARS cannot be used when using "context connection=true" in CLR-procedures: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2575accc-72ac-4fab-99c1-1683afa39d72/context-connection-and-multipleactiveresultsets-can-have-both-at-the-same-time?forum=sqlnetfx

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475195/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c/20535263#20535263

Comment: I verified this on sql server express 2008, I had got this problem after migrate a sql server compact edition 3.5 installation.

Answer (score 7):

You can't perform an action on that connection while it's still working on reading the contents of a data reader - the error is pretty descriptive.

Your alternatives are:

1) Retrieve all your data first, either with a DataSet or use the reader to populate some other collection, then run them all at once after the initial select is done.

2) Use a different connection for your insert statements.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to read the information you need into a list and then iterating the list to perform your inserts like so:

```
        List<String> values = new List<String>();
        using(SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT field1, field2 FROM sourcetable", objConn)) {
            using(SqlDataReader objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
                while(objDataReader.Read()) {
                    values.Add(objDataReader[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        foreach(String value in values) {
            using(SqlCommand objInsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (3, '" + value + "')", objConn)) {
                objInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer so far that's safely disposing of the Commands and the Reader

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2)
    SELECT 3, field1 FROM sourcetable
```

A single SQL statement instead of one per insert.  Not sure if this will work for your real-life problem, but for the example you provided, this is a much better query than doing them one at a time.

On a side note, make sure your code uses parameterized queries instead of accepting strings as-is inside the SQL statement - your sample is open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Several suggestions have been given which work great, along with recommendations for improving the implementation. I hit the MARS limit due to existing code not cleaning up a reader so I wanted to put together a more respectable sample:

```
const string connectionString = @"server=.\sqlexpress;database=adventureworkslt;integrated security=true";
const bool useMARS = false;
using (var objConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString + (useMARS ? ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True" : String.Empty)))
using (var objInsertConn = useMARS ? null : new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 objConn.Open();
 if (objInsertConn != null)
 {
  objInsertConn.Open();
 }

 using (var testCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
 {
  testCmd.Connection = objConn;
  testCmd.CommandText = @"if not exists(select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'sourcetable')
                          begin
                           create table sourcetable (field1 int, field2 varchar(5))
                           insert into sourcetable values (1, 'one')
                           create table tablename (field1 int, field2 varchar(5))
                          end";
  testCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }

 using (var objCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT field1, field2 FROM sourcetable", objConn))
 using (var objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader())
 using (var objInsertCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (3, @field2)", objInsertConn ?? objConn))
 {
  objInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("field2", String.Empty));
  while (objDataReader.Read())
  {
   objInsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = objDataReader[0];
   objInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**
Must execute query and load data before running another query.

**Option 2:** 
 Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to the provider part of your connection string. See the example below:

```
<add name="DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userName;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Server are you using? The problem might be with this:

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

> When you use versions of SQL Server before SQL Server 2005, while the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is busy serving the SqlDataReader. While in this state, no other operations can be performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it. This is the case until the Close method of the SqlDataReader is called.

So, if this is what's causing your problem, you should first read all the data, then close the SqlDataReader, and only after that execute your inserts.

Something like:

```
objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT field1, field2 FROM sourcetable", objConn);

objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

List<object> values = new List<object>();
while (objDataReader.Read())
{
    values.Add(objDataReader[0]);
}

objDataReader.Close();

foreach (object value in values)
{
    objInsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (3, '" + value + "')", objConn);
    objInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to connection string should fix the problem.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//Add a second connection based on the first one
SqlConnection objConn2= new SqlConnection(objConn.connectionString))

SqlCommand objInsertCommand= new SqlCommand();
objInsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objInsertCommand.Connection = objConn2;

while (objDataReader.Read())
{
    objInsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (3, '" + objDataReader[0] + "')";
    objInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This won't work - it's the same thing as what the OP is already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution: 
There is only problem with your "CommandText" value. Let it be SP or normal Sql Query.

- Check 1: The parameter value which you are passing in your Sql Query
  is not changing and going same again and again in your ExecuteReader.
- Check 2: Sql Query string is wrongly formed.
- Check 3: Please create simplest code as follows.

  ```
  string ID = "C8CA7EE2";
  string myQuery = "select * from ContactBase where contactid=" + "'" + ID + "'";
  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM_SQL_CONN_UAT"].ToString(); 
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, con);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
  con.Close();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to be disposed easily i use the following coding-template :

```
`using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from SomeTable";
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    if(reader.HasRows)
                    { 
                       while(reader.Read()){
                       // assuming that we've a 1-column(Id) table 
                       int id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()); 

                       }
                    }
                }
            } 
            connection.Close()
        }`
```

Comment: Did you open the connection before executing reader? Are you sure you're reading data correctly?

Comment: I've updated my answer, if it's not working still, please upload your code on Gist or something, so that i can be more helpful