# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. can't I open new data reader in existing data reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

can't I open new data reader in existing data reader?? plzz help me. i'm new to c#

```
string statement11 = "SELECT Planning FROM allow where NPLID=(SELECT MAX(NPLID) FROM allow)";

SqlCommand myCommand11 = new SqlCommand(statement11, con1);
SqlDataReader plan2 = myCommand11.ExecuteReader();
while(plan2.Read())

if (!plan2.IsDBNull(0) && "ok" == plan2.GetString(0))
{
    string statement99 = "SELECT Dropplan FROM NPLQAnew where NPLID=(SELECT MAX(NPLID) FROM allow)";
    SqlDataReader myReader1 = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand114 = new SqlCommand(statement99, con1);
    SqlDataReader plandrop = myCommand114.ExecuteReader();
    while (plandrop.Read())
        if (plandrop.IsDBNull(0) && plandrop.GetString(0) == "Red")
        {

            Lblplan1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else if (plandrop.IsDBNull(0) && "amber" == plandrop.GetString(0))
        {

            Lblplan1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (plandrop.IsDBNull(0) && "Green" == plandrop.GetString(0))
        {
            Lblplan1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    plandrop.Close();


    this.Lblplan1.Visible = true;



}

plan2.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [error 'there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839569/error-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-mu)

Comment: using Statement (C# Reference): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: Cant execute two querys at the same time...

Answer (score 3):

By default, the SQL Server client will not let you open two simultaneous queries on the same connection. If you are in the process of reading the results of one data reader, for example, you cannot use the same connection to start reading from a second. And, with the way that SQL Server connection pooling works, even asking for a "new" connection is not guaranteed to work either.

You have a couple of options on how to fix this. The first is to refactor your code to eliminate the nested SQL execute calls; for example, load the results of your first query into memory before you loop through and process them.

An easier answer is to enable "MARS" - [Multiple Active Recordsets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) - on your connection. This is done be setting the `"MARS Connection=True` option on the connection string to turn the feature on. This is *generally* pretty safe to do, and it's only off by default to preserve the pre-2005 behavior for old applications, but you the linked article does give some guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string

Answer (score 0):

No you cant perform this on same connection, but you can achieve by 
**[Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cfa084cz.aspx)**, am hoping you having sqlserver 2005 and above.

or

You need to  different connection to be opened for the second command.

Answer (score 0):

Use **USING** statement.  The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called.

For error : There is already data reader attached to current connection string. Try to close the data reader first.

Answer (score 0):

after this line

```
  if (!plan2.IsDBNull(0) && "ok" == plan2.GetString(0))
  {
   //open a new sql connection here
   //your string statement99

    :
    :


  // then close your second sql connection here before the  last  }  

  }
```